# Why do I get a segmentation fault here?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, nodes, mergesort

```
void LinkedList<T>::mergeSort(Node*& curr) {
    if (curr->next != nullptr) { //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)
        Node *ptr1 = nullptr;
        Node *ptr2 = curr;
        //splits linked list
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength() / 2; i++) {
            ptr1 = ptr2;
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
        }
        ptr1->next = nullptr;
        ptr1 = curr;
        //recursive call for sorting
        mergeSort(ptr1); //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)
        mergeSort(ptr2);
        //merge lists back together
        if (ptr1 == nullptr)
            curr = ptr2
        else if (ptr2 == nullptr)
            curr = ptr1

        Node *reff = ptr1;

        while (reff->next != nullptr) {
            reff = reff->next;
        }
        reff->next = ptr2;
        curr = reff;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working, expect this function. I always get a segmentation error and I'm confused why it happens.

Also, I'm in college so there might be a more efficient way but this is the way I can do it, without looking ahead into the course.

I have a variable called length that holds the length. That part was implemented by the teacher.

So it gives me this error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)`. How can I figure out what the error means by code=2 and other numbers?

Comment: These kind of questions are best answered by pouring yourself a cup of coffee and stepping through your program with a debugger. I didn't learn how to properly use a debugger until well after college, and I really wish that hadn't been the case. Learn to use it if you don't know how!

Comment: There are several places where you are potentially dereferencing a null pointer. [Edit] the question to include the details of your error, and what line it is happening on?

Comment: how does `getLength()` know then the length of the argument `curr`?

Comment: Turbo Debugger is the only reason I had free time during my stay in Computer Science.

Comment: you prob. also need to return something see [Top-down implementation using lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists)

Comment: @Thomas I have a variable called length that holds the length. That part was implemented by the teacher.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ok I edited the question

Comment: `         curr=ptr2` seems to be missing a semicolon?

Comment: As an aside, it seems like the "merge" part of your mergesort attempts to just append one of the recursive results to the other. That's not the correct algorithm; check the textbook again.

Comment: @AbbasZaidi but you have two "sublists", `ptr1`, `ptr2`. surely their length is different

Answer (score 3):

There are prob. numerous things wrong. This shows how it can be done with `std::list`. I don't know whether the API was given, but lets make it separate function that takes a list.

```
template<typename T>
void mergesort( std::list<T>& list ){
```

There is only work to do if we have more than one element

```
    auto const size = list.size();
    if( size > 1) {
```

The list is then split into two lists.

```
        auto mid = list.begin();
        std::advance( mid, size/2 );        
        std::list<T> other;        
        other.splice( other.begin(), list, list.begin(), mid );
```

Now that we have two sub-lists, mergesort can be called recursively on them.

```
    mergesort( list );
    mergesort( other );
```

The partial results then need to be merged.

```
    list.merge( other );
```

And we are done. See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fea3bc176c0104d0)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<getLength()/2;i++)
```

> I have a variable called length that holds the length. That part was implemented by the teacher.

So, `getLength()` is a member function of the `LinkedList`. When we make the recursive calls, it will always tell us the stored `length` of the entire `LinkedList`. But that's not what we want - we want the number of nodes in the chain of `Node`s that we passed in. Instead, the first time we make a recursive call, we try to split it into the same number of nodes as it already has (in the first half, and zero nodes in the second half). Since this makes no progress, we will eventually blow up the stack with recursive calls.